# Update column of dataframe1 based on column of dataframe2 + create new row if column1 is not empty

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I have a dataframe that I want to update with information from another dataframe, a lookup dataframe.

In particular, I'd like to update the cells of df1$value with the cells of `df2$value` based on the columns `id` and `id2`.

- If the cell of `df1$value` is `NA`, I know how to do it using the package `data.table`

BUT

- If the cell of `df1$value` is not empty, data.table will update it with the cell of `df2$value` anyway.

I don't want that. I'd like to have that:

IF the cell of `df1$value` is NOT empty (in this case the row in which `df1$id` is `c`), do not update the cell but create a duplicate row of df1 in which the cell of df1$value takes the value from the cell of `df2$value`

I already looked for solutions online but I couldn't find any. Is there a way to do it easily with tidyverse or data.table or an `sql-like` package?

Thank you for your help!

edit: I've just realized that I forgot to put the corner case in which in both dataframes the row is NA. With the replies I had so far (`07/08/19 14:42`) the row `e` is removed from the last dataframe. But I really need to keep it!

Outline:

```
> df1
  id id2 value
1 a         1   100
2 b         2   101
3 c         3    50
4 d         4    NA
5 e         5    NA

> df2
  id id2 value
1 c         3   200
2 d         4   201
3 e         5    NA

# I'd like:

> df5
  id id2 value
1 a         1   100
2 b         2   101
3 c         3    50
4 c         3   200
5 d         4   201
6 e         5    NA
```

This is how I managed to solve my problem but it's quite cumbersome.

```
# I create the dataframes
df1 <- data.frame(id=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), id2=c(1,2,3,4),value=c(100, 101, 50, NA))
df2 <- data.frame(id=c('c', 'd', 'e'),id2=c(3,4, 5), value=c(200, 201, 300))

# I first do a left_join so I'll have two value columnes: value.x and value.y
df3 <- dplyr::left_join(df1, df2, by = c("id","id2"))

# > df3
#   id id2 value.x value.y
# 1  a   1     100      NA
# 2  b   2     101      NA
# 3  c   3      50     200
# 4  d   4      NA     201

# I keep only the rows in which value.x is NA, so the 4th row
df4 <- df3 %>%
  filter(is.na(value.x)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(id, id2, value.y)

# > df4
#   id id2 value.y
# 1  d   4     201

# I rename the column "value.y" to "value". (I don't do it with dplyr because the function dplyr::replace doesn't work in my R version)
colnames(df4)[colnames(df4) == "value.y"] <- "value"

# > df4
#   id id2 value
# 1  d   4     201

# I update the df1 with the df4$value. This step is necessary to update only the rows of df1 in which df1$value is NA
setDT(df1)[setDT(df4), on = c("id","id2"), `:=`(value = i.value)]

# > df1
#    id id2 value
# 1:  a   1   100
# 2:  b   2   101
# 3:  c   3    50
# 4:  d   4   201

# I filter only the rows in which both value.x and value.y are NAs
df3 <- as_tibble(df3) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value.x), !is.na(value.y)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(id, id2, value.y)

# > df3
# # A tibble: 1 x 3
#   id      id2 value.y
#   <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 c         3     200

# I rename column df3$value.y to value
colnames(df3)[colnames(df3) == "value.y"] <- "value"

# I bind by rows df1 and df3 and I order by the column id
df5 <- rbind(df1, df3) %>% 
  arrange(id)

# > df5
#   id id2 value
# 1  a   1   100
# 2  b   2   101
# 3  c   3    50
# 4  c   3   200
# 5  d   4   201
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `full_join` and `gather`

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df1, df2, by = c("id","id2")) %>%
   tidyr::gather(key, value, starts_with("value"), na.rm = TRUE) %>%
   select(-key)

#   id id2 value
#1   a   1   100
#2   b   2   101
#3   c   3    50
#7   c   3   200
#8   d   4   201
```

For the updated case, we can do

```
left_join(df1, df2, by = c("id","id2")) %>%
   tidyr::gather(key, value, starts_with("value")) %>%
   group_by(id, id2) %>%
   filter((all(is.na(value)) & !duplicated(value)) | !is.na(value)) %>%
   select(-key)

#  id      id2 value
#  <chr> <int> <int>
#1 a         1   100
#2 b         2   101
#3 c         3    50
#4 e         5    NA
#5 c         3   200
#6 d         4   201
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn' think about doing it like that! But I have to point out that I don't want the rows of df2 that do not match df1. So, in this case, instead of using `full_join` I need to use `left_join` :)

Comment: Dear Ronak. I've just realized that I forgot to put a corner case in my code and now I'm stuck again. Would you be so kind as to give a look ad my edited question?

Answer (score 3):

A left join with data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1); setDT(df2)

df2[df1, on=.(id, id2), .(value = 
  if (.N == 0) i.value 
  else na.omit(c(i.value, x.value))
), by=.EACHI]

   id id2 value
1:  a   1   100
2:  b   2   101
3:  c   3    50
4:  c   3   200
5:  d   4   201
```

*How it works*: The syntax is `x[i, on=, j, by=.EACHI]`: for each row of `i = df1` do `j`.

In this case `j = .(value = expr)` where `.()` is a shortcut to `list()` since in general `j` should return a list of columns.

Regarding the expression, `.N` is the number of rows of `x = df2` that are found for each row of `i = df1`, so if no matches are found we keep values from `i`; and otherwise we keep values from both tables, dropping missing values.

---

A dplyr way:

```
bind_rows(df1, semi_join(df2, df1, by=c("id", "id2"))) %>% 
  group_by(id, id2) %>% 
  do(if (nrow(.) == 1) . else na.omit(.))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   id, id2 [4]
  id      id2 value
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         1   100
2 b         2   101
3 c         3    50
4 c         3   200
5 d         4   201
```

*Comment*. The dplyr way is kind of awkward because `do()` is needed to get a dynamically determined number of rows, but `do()` is typically discouraged and does not support `n()` and other helper functions. The data.table way is kind of awkward because there is no simple semi join functionality.

---

*Data*:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), id2=c(1,2,3,4),value=c(100, 101, 50, NA))
df2 <- data.frame(id=c('c', 'd', 'e'),id2=c(3,4, 5), value=c(200, 201, 300))

> df1
  id id2 value
1  a   1   100
2  b   2   101
3  c   3    50
4  d   4    NA
> df2
  id id2 value
1  c   3   200
2  d   4   201
3  e   5   300
```

Answer (score 2):

Another idea via base R is to remove the rows from `df2` that do not match in `df1`, bind the two data frames rowwise (`rbind`) and omit the NAs, i.e.

```
na.omit(rbind(df1, df2[do.call(paste, df2[1:2]) %in% do.call(paste, df1[1:2]),]))

#  id id2 value
#1  a   1   100
#2  b   2   101
#3  c   3    50
#5  c   3   200
#6  d   4   201
```

To answer your new requirements, we can keep the same `rbind` method and filter based on your conditions, i.e.

```
dd <- rbind(df1, df2[do.call(paste, df2[1:2]) %in% do.call(paste, df1[1:2]),])
dd[!!with(dd, ave(value, id, id2, FUN = function(i)(all(is.na(i)) & !duplicated(i)) | !is.na(i))),]

#  id id2 value
#1  a   1   100
#2  b   2   101
#3  c   3    50
#5  e   5    NA
#6  c   3   200
#7  d   4   201
```

Comment: Dear Sotos, thank you for your answer. I've just realized that I forgot to put a corner case in my code and now I'm stuck again. Would you be so kind as to give a look ad my edited question? :)

Comment: Edited based on your new conditions

Answer (score 2):

A possible approach with data.table using update join then full outer merge:

```
merge(df1[is.na(value), value := df2[.SD, on=.(id, id2), x.value]], df2, all=TRUE)
```

output:

```
   id id2 value
1:  a   1   100
2:  b   2   101
3:  c   3    50
4:  c   3   200
5:  d   4   201
6:  e   5    NA
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.table(id=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), id2=c(1,2,3,4,5),value=c(100, 101, 50, NA, NA))
df2 <- data.table(id=c('c', 'd', 'e'), id2=c(3,4, 5), value=c(200, 201, NA))
```